# foreach loop assigns incorrect str value to error var based on current condition

Tags: php

I have a function to check whether or not a data entry a user is attempting to add to a mySQL DB exists or not. Although I don't allow the tuple in the DB table to allow the insertion of duplicates, this function is merely for the benefit of the user so they know with an easy to understand error message why their data entry was refused.

So there are two numbers to check, both unique, listed in the example as **ourNum => $ourNum** and **venNum => $venNum**. The problem is that when the func checks the first array element (**ourNum**), and it fails because mysqli_query succeeds, the resulting **$errMsg** displays that it was **$venNum** that already exists rather than **$ourNum**. Now **$venNum** may in fact, actually should in fact prove also to be duplicate since **$ourNum** can only exist in the DB alongside a valid **$venNum**, but the message for the use is mis-informative and plain wrong.

```
function eqpt_num_dupe_check( $ourNum, $venNum, &$errMsg ){

  // create associative array to hold ourNum => $ourNum and venNum => $venNum
  $eqptNumArr = array(
    'ourNum' => $ourNum,
    'venNum' => $venNum );

  // check for duplicate eqptNum entry
  foreach ( $eqptNumArr as $eqpt => $num ) {
    $sqlQ = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE $eqpt = $num";

    if ( $rs = mysqli_query( $dbcon, $sqlQ ) ) { // if $rs is assigned then eqptNum already exists in DB, so display errMsg for user
      $errMsg = 'Data entry refused: ' . $eqpt . ': ' . $num . ' already exists in database.';
    }
  }
}
```

It seems as though **foreach** has already moved onto the array's 2nd element before the first element's data duplicity **$errMsg** is displayed to the user.

Comment: You are overwriting the errMsg every loop, some solutions: return the error msg instead of assigning it, place a break in the foreach an error occurse or use an array of errors instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `break` in the `if` conditional after `$errMsg` is assigned so that no further processing takes place when duplicate data is discovered.

```
if ( $rs = mysqli_query( $dbcon, $sqlQ ) ) { // if $rs is assigned then eqptNum already exists in DB, so display errMsg for user
    $errMsg = 'Data entry refused: ' . $eqpt . ': ' . $num . ' already exists in database.';
    break;
}
```

Without the `break` the `foreach` merrily continues loading subsequent array elements, processing each until there are no more elements to load. The `break` stops this processing precisely when duplicate data is found, and so will display the correct `$errMsg` for the user. If `$venNum` also proves to be a duplicate then it will be correctly detected only when the user enters a unique value for `$ourNum`.

`if (!$rs)` then the next array element is loaded up an run thru `mysqli_query` to check for its possible duplicity.